# При создании динамического массива объектов получаю ошибку

Tags: java, arraylist

При создании динамического массива объектов (строка 10) получаю ошибку. Со статическим объектом все работало:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at main$hash.get(main.java:50)
    at main.main(main.java:75)
```

```java
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class main {
        static class hash {
            String FIO;
            String group;
            int number;
            int key;
            ArrayList<hash> arr = new ArrayList<>(20);
    
            hash(){};
            hash(int number, String group, String FIO, int key){
                this.number = number;
                this.group = group;
                this.FIO = FIO;
                this.key = key;
            }
    
            int hash_f1(int key){
                return key%20;
            }
            int hash_f2(int key){
                return key+10;
            }
            void setKey(int key){
                this.key = key;
            }
    
            void output(){
                for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
                    System.out.print(i + " - " );
                    System.out.println("Номер - " + arr.get(i).number + "; Группа - "+ arr.get(i).group + "; ФИО -" + arr.get(i).FIO + "; key - " + arr.get(i).key);
                }
            }
            void get(String line) throws IOException {
    
                FIO = group = line;
    
    
                line = line.substring(0, 4);
                group = group.substring(5, 15);
                FIO = FIO.substring(16, 26);
    
                number = Integer.parseInt(line);
                key = hash_f1(number);
    
                hash H_obj = new hash(number, group, FIO, key);
                //System.out.println(number + "\n" + group +"\n" + FIO);
                if(arr.get(hash_f1(number)) == null) {
                    arr.add(hash_f1(number),H_obj);
                }else{
                    this.setKey(hash_f2(hash_f1(number)));
                    arr.add(hash_f2(hash_f1(number)),H_obj);
                }
    
            }
            void delete(int n){
    
            };
            void add(int n){
    
            };
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            hash x = new hash();
            File file = new File("D://IntelliJ IDEA/projects/siaod/text.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
    
    
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                x.get(line);
            }
            x.output();
        }
    }
```

Может я неправильно его заполняю? Или он игнорирует аргумент 20 при создании? Динамический массив нужен для создания методов удаления/добавления/рехеширования.

Comment: Как-то странновато у Вас всё. А как же соглашение? Почему имена классов с маленькой буквы... А вот логику я не очень понял. Вы делаете статический класс, чтобы... потом писать hash x = new hash(); ? А при его инициализации нужно ещё сделать список с 20 такими же хешами... я что-то запутался ) Попробуйте удалить hash x = new hash(); и заменить это строчкой ArrayList<hash> arr = new ArrayList<>(20); . Из класса её собственно убрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-

```
ArrayList<hash> arr = new ArrayList<>(20);
```

`20` - это не `count`, а `capacity`

Comment: Capacity это же емкость? Я думал определяю начальную емкость массива... Что мне тогда надо использовать?

Comment: @SelectionForCollection В программировании прямой перевод из англо-русского словаря работает не всегда. `Capacity` в данном случае означает начальный размер внутреннего хранилища, куда будут помещаться ссылки на элементы списка, - когда эти ссылки будут добавлены в список. Что Вам использовать - я не знаю. В каком порядке код обращается к элементам списка? Может быть Вам следует использовать `Map`, а не `List`.